# javascript function calling issue

Tags: javascript, function

I can't understand why calling the debounce function on case 2. Does not work and on case 1 does...

`<input type="text" oninput="logText()" id="ti">`

1. This works:

`var logText = debounce(getInputValue, 400)`

2. This does not work:

`function logText() {
  debounce(getInputValue, 400)
}`

```
function getInputValue(e) {
  var inputT = document.getElementById('ti')
  var inputText = inputT.value
  console.log(inputText)
}

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) { /**/}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: A) What does "working" mean? What does this do? B) What *does* it do? Errors? Incorrect output?

Comment: because debounce returns a function that you need to execute. So it does not work because you are using it wrong.... 1 is the correct way to use it, 2 is the incorrect way

Comment: by working i mean, 1. logs the the input value with a delay, and on 2, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `debounce` takes in the arguments of a function and a time value. It wraps the supplied function with some logic so it is called and the method returns a function that you trigger to say you want to run this.

So in the first one you are setting the retuned function to a variable and that variable gets called on click. That is how you are supposed to use it.

Your second one calls the debounce function and does nothing with the returned function. So that function is never executed. It also makes no sense to execute it since you would be creating a new instance of the debounce function which would defeat the purpose of what you are trying to solve. It would be no different than just calling `getInputValue` directly. Or depending what the debounce is written to do, it will be 400ms delay.

Comment: Don't agree with the last part of your answer: by changing the definition of the `logText` function to `function logText() {   debounce(getInputValue, 400)() }`, thus immediately executing the function created by `debounce`, the second way would work exactly the same as the first (i.e. delayed execution of `getInputValue`, not like a direct call of `getInputValue`).

Comment: The debounce call will call it.... so it is not like the debounce call is there... It depends on what the library does with `immediate` So if it is, than it is delayed by 400 and called, but still there will be no debouncing of additional calls.

Comment: Did you notice the two extra brackets `()` in the version of `logText` in the above comment?